# How access a key of a array which is returned by a function

Tags: php, chaining

I want to be able to access the array directly from the return value of the function.

```
e.g. 
$arr = find_student();
echo $arr['name'];

// I want to be able to do
echo find_student()['name']
```

How can I accomplish the same ? Without another line of code ?

Comment: what you want can't be done. you have to assign the return value to a variable first

Comment: Wait a few weeks/months for PHP 5.4 which (I believe) does allow this syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. The PHP syntax parser is limited and does not allow it in current versions.

The PHP devs extended the parser for upcoming releases of PHP. Here's a link to a [blog talking about it](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html)

Answer (score 2):

You cant :)

```
function find_student() {return array('name'=>123);}
echo find_student()['name'];
```

Result:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 2):

You can do something similiar using [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php).

```
function find_student() {
//Generating the array..
$array = array("name" => "John", "age" => "23");

return new ArrayObject($array);
}

echo find_student()->name;
// Equals to
$student = find_student();
echo $student['name'];
```

Downside is you cant use native array functions like `array_merge()` on that. But you can access you data as you would on array and like on an object.

Comment: yep, i guess, this is one way of doing it. Thanks

Comment: Also, if you wanted to use array functions you could just do this: (array)find_student();